# Problem in Print Composser in Q-GIS+Google Earth_Vector lines

Tags: google-maps, qgis-openlayers-plugin

I am facing problem in map making using Qgis with Google earth view and overlapping vector layers, please see the attachment and help to solved this problem.

Actually, during take any output with google earth image and vector lines, vectors lines are distorted from its original position. [image]

Answer (score 1):

I run into this problem several times. Unfortunately there seems to be no solution for it (I asked about it in this forum some time ago). It is simply a bug.

For me it sometimes (but only sometimes) worked to use Bing instead of Google.
The best way around this problem for me was to export the needed satelite image from Google Earth Pro and then georeference it manually in QGIS using the Google Earth map from the Openlayer plugin. The georeferenced satelite image always worked without problems.